# C++ constexpr keyword placement

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have recently started using more C++11 features in my code and I have been wondering if the placement of the `constexpr` keyword makes difference whether it is before or after the constant's type.

**Style 1:**

```
constexpr int FOO = 1;
constexpr auto BAR = "bar";
```

**Style 2:**

```
int constexpr FOO = 1;
auto constexpr BAR = "bar";
```

Style 2 is the way I prefer to place the `const` keyword and placing `constexpr` the same way would bring some consistency to the code. However, is that considered bad practice or is there something else wrong with style 2 because I don't really see anyone writing it like that.

Comment: Also a nice explanation: [East const but constexpr West - Dan Saks](https://youtu.be/z6s6bacI424)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a specifier, like `long`, `short`, `unsigned`, etc. They can all be moved around. For example, the following are two equivalent and valid declarations:

```
int long const long unsigned constexpr foo = 5;
constexpr const unsigned long long int foo = 5;
```

By convention, though, `constexpr` would appear before the type name. It can confuse others if you put it after, but it is technically valid. Since `constexpr` serves a different purpose than `const`, I don't see the same benefit in putting it to the right. For example, you can't do `int constexpr * constexpr foo`. In fact, `int constexpr * foo` will not allow you to reassign `foo`, rather than apply to what `foo` points to, so putting it to the right can be misleading if you expect the same kind of semantics as `const`.

To summarize:

```
int constexpr foo = 0; // valid
int constexpr * constexpr foo = nullptr; // invalid
int* constexpr foo = nullptr; // invalid
int constexpr * foo = nullptr; // valid
constexpr int* foo = nullptr; // valid and same as previous
```

Comment: Just regarding wording. "_They can all be moved around_" could be understood as "_it does not matter where you put `const`_", which is not the case since it changes the meaning.

Comment: @AlexD, True, I might have oversimplified it a bit. The main point was that they can appear in any order, before or after the "base type" (e.g., `int`), until something like `*`, where the grammar starts getting more specific. Declaration grammar isn't one of the simplest parts.

Comment: Sure. As I said, my remark was just about wording :-).

Comment: The relevant nonterminal is the *decl-specifier-seq*, but that's not particularly easy to understand, either.

Comment: Actually they(declaration specifier) indeed **can** be moved around, if within the "declaration specifier sequence" part(not within the declarator part such as after `*`). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033271/10027592) and [this](https://youtu.be/z6s6bacI424) are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956974.aspx) defines the syntax as:

> **constexpr**  literal-type  identifier = constant-expression;constexpr  literal-type  identifier { constant-expression };constexpr literal-type identifier(params );constexpr ctor (params);

Which says that you should use it on the left.

**Edit:**

> New specifier The keyword constexpr is a declaration specifier; modify the
>   grammar in [ISO03, §7.1] as follows:
>
> 1 The specifiers that can be used in a declaration are
>   decl-specifier:
>
> storage-class-specifier
>
> type-specifier
>
> function-specifier
>
> friend
>
> typedef
>
> constexpr

An explanation is given for this specifiers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations).

To sum up @chris' answer is right :)