# Is east constexpr / constinit / consteval allowed in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

Most examples I found on the web preferred the "west style" for `constexpr` (C++11), `consteval`, and `constinit` (C++20):

```cpp
consteval auto sqr(int n) {
  return n*n;
}
constexpr auto r = sqr(100);  // OK
constinit static auto x = r;
```

Since I`m not a language lawyer, I have the following question: 
Is the "east style" allowed for these specifiers? Example:

```cpp
auto consteval sqr(int n) {
  return n*n;
}
auto constexpr r = sqr(100);  // OK
static auto constinit x = r;
```

To be clear: I do not intent to start a "west" / "east" language war. I'm not interested in opinions, just in facts, especially as clang and gcc head versions on wandbox at this moment give errors but no answers on `constinit` / `consteval`.

Comment: Note that `constinit` could still be accompanied with a non-redundant `const` (as opposed to `constexpr`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sort of.

It's part of the *decl-specifier-seq*, and the specifiers in that can be in any order. It's the same rule that allows you to write `volatile int static long unsigned inline long const x = 1;`

But it isn't part of the *declarator* (in particular, the *ptr-operator*), so you can't do `int* constexpr x = nullptr;`.

Comment: That type is a monstrosity, and you know it.

Comment: One can use C++ for years without knowing types like this are in fact valid.

Comment: Accurate explanation. Also [helpful vid](https://youtu.be/z6s6bacI424), together with this answer :)